# How the mass is calculate with 3D print addon

Tags: add-on

I have 2 mesh with same size and same verts, Why the mass is showing different. To right it is showing 5Kg and To left it is showing 20Kg.

[image]

[image]

Before What i did is i put the value 5Kg in rigid body -> mass and in object -> rigid body -> calculate mass i have selected custom and put the value of 7200.
In the 3d Addon -> Transform -> I click on Scale to Volume. A pop-up with some value just click on OK. This way i have got different value. 5Kg and 20 Kg.

Without changing the size and same verts how the mass is set? Any suggestion. Did my mesh scale but it did not how the mass is set to different values. Thanks